# Regex search for strings with extra spaces for a given word

Tags: regex

Here is a string:

```
foo
```

I want to find all occurrence of strings that have at least one space between characters, i.e.:

```
(f oo|fo o|f o o)
```

However, if the length is longer, I cannot simply do like the above.

I tried

```
f\s?o\s?o
```

But in this case, "foo" will be matched too.

### UPDATE

As @CertainPerformace clarified:

> The whole string needs to contain at least one space, but it doesn't matter where and how many, as long as there's at least one somewhere

However, I don't want words like `b ar` to be matched. I want foo-but-with-extra-spaces strings to be matched.

For example, given a string

```
foo f oo f o o b ar
```

I want only `f oo` and `f o o` to be matched.

Comment: Do you mean, the whole string needs to contain at least one space, but it doesn't matter where and how many, as long as there's at least one somewhere?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, see the first example. I need an equivalent of it

Comment: There are things that are best done without regex.

Comment: @Blackhole, you got a point. Any javascript solution?

Comment: @bravemaster Search for `f ?o ?o` (that is, `'foo'.split().join(' ?')`) and count the number of space afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After matching the first character, lookahead for zero to `n - 2` non-space characters, followed by a space, where `n` is the length of the string. For example, with `foo`, you'd repeat non-spaces up to 1 time. That'll ensure that a space occurs before the characters in the word you want run out.

Then, end the lookahead, and match the letters normally, possible with spaces in between:

```
f(?=\S{0,1} ) *o *o
```

https://regex101.com/r/nzejCS/3

For a longer word, like `foobar`, you'd do:

```
f(?=\S{0,4} ) *o *o *b *a *r
```

You can also negative lookahead at the beginning:

```
(?!foo)f *o *o
```

https://regex101.com/r/nzejCS/4

Comment: What if the words are in one line? For example `foo f oo f o o`. I removed caret and dollar sign from your solution but then `foo` is also matched.

Comment: Using the same pattern in the answer, that string matches as well: https://regex101.com/r/nzejCS/2 The pattern makes sure that it contains at least one space, then it matches the whole rest of the text.

Comment: The point is, the regex should not find words like `b ar`. It should find foo-but-extra-space words.

Comment: Should multiple occurrences of the original word match, like your `foo f oo f o o`, or must it only be 1 full word?

Comment: In `foo f oo f o o b ar`, I want only `f oo`, `f o o` to be matched

Comment: Edited version seems to be working. I have an idea. What about search for `f\s?o\s?o` and exclude `foo`? I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: Sure, you could do that, it looks a bit nicer too. `(?!foo)f *o *o`

Comment: Can you add that to your answer too? :) Thanks